# How to detect window index of firefox?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to get the window index (position) firefox on desktop with Applescript. 
I got to this far but I don't know how to proceed. Can somebody point to me some example code or clue. :-|

```
tell application "System Events"
    set programs to processes whose visible is true and name is "firefox-bin" or name is "google chrome" or name is "safari"

    repeat with program in programs
        tell window of application program
            #XXX do something   
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to know some property of the window you want to identify. In my example I assume you know the name of the window.

```
set windowName to "some name"
set windowIndex to missing value

tell application "System Events"
    set programs to processes whose visible is true and name is "firefox-bin" or name is "google chrome" or name is "safari"

    repeat with program in programs
        tell program
            set windowNames to name of windows
            repeat with i from 1 to count of windowNames
                if windowName is item i of windowNames then
                    set windowIndex to i
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell

return windowIndex
```